# Django/template_block doesn't be operated

Tags: django, django-templates

Thanks in advance.

I have a code below "index.html"

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
 {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

and I have another html code("maintab.html") for child of "index.html"

```html
{% extends "encyclopeida/index.html" %}
{% block content %}
<p>Hello world</p>
{% endblock %}
```

but it doesn't work.. 
my contact path is 
"browser -> "http://localhost/encyclopedia/"(by urls) -> function def("by view.py") -> index.html"

and below is my folder structure.

[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eB57B.jpg)

and finally this is my setting.py and view.py

```html
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'encyclopedia.apps.EncyclopediaConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'projectstarbucks.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'projectstarbucks.wsgi.application'
```

```html
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Content, Service

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    source_list = Content.objects.order_by('id')
    menu_list = Service.objects.order_by('id')
    context = {'source_list':source_list,'menu_list':menu_list}
    return render(request, 'encyclopedia/index.html', context)
```

Comment: include settings.py tepmlate section and also add `views.py`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? For `<p>Hello world</p>` to appear?

Comment: @JahongirRahmonov yes. I want to call index.html then paste maintab.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing `maintab.html` here

```
def index(request):
    source_list = Content.objects.order_by('id')
    menu_list = Service.objects.order_by('id')
    context = {'source_list':source_list,'menu_list':menu_list}
    return render(request, 'encyclopedia/maintab.html', context)
```

Comment: So, after calling maintab... then call index.html?

Comment: @Yongwoon.jang, You don't need to call `index.html` it will automatically inherit `index.html` when `maintab.html` is displayed.

Comment: thanks but if I need another child of index.html? Just add {block ...} in index.html?

Comment: I am not getting can you explain further what you exactly want to do.

Comment: um... thx for your consideration. I just want to make “index.html” have many child templates.

Comment: I solve the problem. and I think that Django system's template just use 1 chidren per one parent. thanks.!

Answer (score 0):

You need to render `maintab.html` which extends `index.html`.

```
return render(request, 'path/to/maintab.html' ,  context)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to include `mainlab.html` inside `index.html`.

Then, change `mainlab.html` to this:

```
{% block content %}
    <p>Hello world</p>
{% endblock %}
```

And then in your `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
    {% include "maintab.html" %}
</body>
</html>
```